# Socket.io socket emit not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have this index.js file on the client:

```
var socket;

var init = function() {
    // Setup Socket:
    socket = io.connect();

    // Setup Event Handlers:
    setEventHandlers();

    // Connect to Server:
    socket.emit('connect', {
        name : "User Name"
    });

    console.log("Client Init Complete.");
}

var setEventHandlers = function() {
    // Set Routes For Connections
    socket.on("connection resp", onConnected);
}

var onConnected = function(data) {
    console.log(data.resp);
}
```

And I have this code on the server:

```
// SETUP:
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var request = require('request');
var path = require('path');
var socket = require('socket.io')(http);
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '0.0.0.0';
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var fs = require('fs');

// SETUP:
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended : false
}));
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
})

var setEventHandlers = function() {
    socket.sockets.on("connection", onInit); 
};

var onInit = function(client) {
    client.on("connect", onConnect);
};

var onConnect = function(data) {
    console.log("Called");
}

// Send index page html
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile("public/html/index.html");
});

// Turn on server
http.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function() {
    console.log("App Listening on " + server_ip_address + ", server_port "
            + server_port);
});

setEventHandlers();
```

The issue is that on the onConnect on the server is never called. Eventhough I call socket.emit("connect") on the client.

After further testing, it seems that the socket id is undefined: this.id returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes to the parameters in the `socket.emit` function like this:

```
// Connect to Server:
    socket.emit('connect', {
        'name' : 'User Name'
    });
```

Comment: Could you add your html file?

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your socket variable through io.connect("server address") and has i see in your code you have not passed any parameter to io.connect
  .If server is in your local machine then connect to it by io.connect("http://localhost").
For more information see Docs. [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client)